# Need Switching between 2 Mainwindows in Pyqt5

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created 2 separate MainWindow(in 2 different programs). Now I need to switch between these 2 windows. Example: When a button in MainWindow1 is clicked , MainWindow2 should be opened and MainWindow1 should be closed and vice versa. Please help!

Comment: Your code, please!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

class MainWindow1(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.mainWindow1()


    def mainWindow1(self):
        self.setFixedSize(300, 300)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color : rgb(255,255,255);')
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow1')

        self.pushButton = Qt.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,0,0); color: #fff')
        self.pushButton.setText('Click me!')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.A)

    def A(self):
        self.cams = MainWindow2()
        self.cams.show()
        self.close()

class MainWindow2(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color : rgb(255,0,0);')
        self.setWindowTitle('MainWindow2')

        self.pushButton = Qt.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(0,0,255); color: #fff')
        self.pushButton.setText('Click me!')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.B)

    def B(self):
        self.cams = MainWindow1()
        self.cams.show()
        self.close()          


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w   = MainWindow1()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You are not switching between the windows, you are creating new windows of the same type that is very different since when the window state is switched it is recovered but when it is created it does not.

Comment: Thanks a lot eyllanesc... But my concern is i have 2 window as a separate program.... how can I achieve the same with 2 different programs... EX Program 1 for MainWindow1 and Program 2 for MainWindow2...